# Get current letter onScroll?

Tags: android, scroll, accessibility, android-cursoradapter

I'm building an accessibility app and want to read out loud the current letter on the AlphabetIndexer as the user scrolls.

How can I run some code onScroll? And how do I get the current letter inside the CursorAdapter?

Thanks

---

This is what I'm trying (I tried to leave only the relevant bits):

```
private class ContactsAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private AlphabetIndexer mAlphabetIndexer;

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final String alphabet = context.getString(R.string.alphabet);
        mAlphabetIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(null, ContactsQuery.SORT_KEY, alphabet);
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return mAlphabetIndexer.getSections();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int i) {
        if (getCursor() == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        Log.i("TAG", "getPositionForSection " + mAlphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(i));
        return mAlphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int i) {
        if (getCursor() == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SectionIndexer.getSectionForPosition` is going to return the index of the corresponding section within `SectionIndexer.getSections`. So to retrieve the current letter for a section, all you need to do is call:

```
    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int i) {
        if (getCursor() == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        // Prints the letter for the current section
        System.out.println(getSections()[mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(i)]);
        return mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(i);
    }
```

Comment: I just tried this, it works for a while but it randomly crashes with message `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I found the problem, instead of `[i]` it should be `[mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(i)]`

Comment: Oops, yeah. Little oversight on my part. Thanks for making that edit.

Comment: I noticed that randomly getSectionForPosition doesn't get called. Mostly it happens when using the scroll bar instead of swiping up and down, any idea why this may be happening? Thanks

Comment: Kinda difficult to guess. Sorry, nothing really comes to mind at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have your custom `SectionIndexer` override the following:

```
@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section)
{
    int result = super.getPositionForSection(section);
    Log.i("TAG", "getPositionForSection " + result);
    return result;
}
```

This will get called when the user fast scrolls through the list, and you should be able to use the result to get the actual letter from your alphabet array.

Comment: how can I get the letter? Anyway I tried Logging  `getPositionForSection(i)` as you suggested but it seems it's not very accurate, when I scroll down it returns something like: "0,21,0,21,0,21,21,40,21,40,50,70"

Comment: Try logging `getSectionForPosition`, that might be more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a working project [on github with alphabetIndexer](https://github.com/amalChandran/ListviewAlphabetIndexer) and section header. Even that takes contacts from your phone.

You can find the current alpgabet based on the scroll using listner. Have a look at this [activity.](https://github.com/amalChandran/ListviewAlphabetIndexer/blob/master/src/com/amalbit/test/MainActivity.java)

private OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {

```
    private int lastFirstVisibleItem = -1;

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
            int totalItemCount) {
        // firstVisibleItem corresponding to the index of AlphabetIndexer(eg, B-->Alphabet index is 2)
        int sectionIndex = mIndexer.getSectionForPosition(firstVisibleItem);
        //next section Index corresponding to the positon in the listview
        int nextSectionPosition = mIndexer.getPositionForSection(sectionIndex + 1);

        if(firstVisibleItem != lastFirstVisibleItem) {
           if(String.valueOf(alphabet.charAt(sectionIndex)).equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
                      //Play the sound for A.
           }

            lastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        }

      }

   };
```

**Note:**

- The above code might have typos.
- Feel free to run the project in your device or emulator with contacts and make changes accordingly.